# Broker Query for Metadata Date Fields

Tags: broker

I have a business requirement to fetch Components based on a Schema from broker database on the basis of two date fields in metadata: `start_date` and `end_date`.

I will have one date input and the query should only return Components where this specific date lies between the values in the `start_date` and `end_date` metadata fields.

I tried with `MetaValueCriteria` and `CustomDateRangeCriteria` but was not successful.

Do we need to pass a specific date format to query on date fields and how can I use `MetaValueCriteria` with date fields?

Comment: Have you tried something already? Is there something that didn't work as you expected?

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't specify version or whether you're using .Net or Java but the API is similar. I quickly wrote this example to show you how I'd use the 2013 SP1 .Net Content Delivery API for a query like what you describe.

```
var inputDate = DateTime.Now;
var schemaId = 500;

var greaterThanStartDateCriteria = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("start_date", Criteria.GreaterThanOrEqual);
var lessThanEndDateCriteria = new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("end_date", Criteria.LessThanOrEqual);

var startDateCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(greaterThanStartDateCriteria, inputDate);
var endDateCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(lessThanEndDateCriteria, inputDate);

var schemaCriteria = new ItemSchemaCriteria(schemaId);

var combinedCriteria = new AndCriteria(new Criteria[] { schemaCriteria, startDateCriteria, endDateCriteria });
var query = new Query(combinedCriteria);

var results = query.ExecuteQuery();
```